# Bind and access checkbox value within a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my grid view I've a checkbox column, and am binding the gridview with a dictionary. I need to get the corresponding `Id` from the checked boxes.

In my dictionary I've the key values like

```
Id         Name
--         ----
 1         Arts
 2         Science
 3         Engineering
```

Here, I tried to bind the value for this checkbox as

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelItem" value="<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>" 
                                                       runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <%# Eval("Key.Name") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and from the codebehind, I tried like

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridDepartments.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkSelItem = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelItem");

            if (chkSelItem.Checked)
            {
                int departmentId = int.Parse(chkSelItem.Text);
                ////
                ////                 
            }
        }
```

its throwing error, or not showing any value for the checkbox.

I also trid with `FindControl`, but no use of it, coz in the `key & Value` pair am using a class(which inherits another class) and a bool. thats what am trying like this, can anyone help me here, thanks in advance.....

Comment: I have a delete button above the gridview, when I select more than one checkboxes and clicking on the `delete` button, I've to get the corresponding `Id`s and delete the values from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try this one...

Bind id to lable instead of to checkbox as below.

<asp:TemplateField>     
<ItemTemplate>       
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelItem" runat="server" />     

<asp:Label ID="lblSelectedItem" value=<%# Eval("Key.Id")) %> visible="False"/>
</ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>



In codebehind try this

foreach (GridViewRow row in gridDepartments.Rows)         
{             
      CheckBox chkSelItem = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelItem");
       Label lblSelectedItem= (Label)row.FindControl("lblSelectedItem");

      if (chkSelItem.Checked) 
      {
                 int departmentId = int.Parse(lblSelectedItem.Text); 
      }
} 



Hope this is what u want...
```

Comment: ya its a nice idea, binding the `Text` value works like a charm, I can get the Id also, I was thinking how to hide the Text value, u've given such a nice idea, I'll try it and let u know

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
CheckBox chkSelItem = (CheckBox)row.cell[0].FindControl("chkSelItem");// Replace row.cell[0] accrding to you celll index
```

instead of

```
 CheckBox chkSelItem = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelItem");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use Text instead of value as you are assigning to value and getting text property. Text will be empty string and parsing it with int throws exception.

int.Parse(chkSelItem.Text);

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelItem" value="<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>" runat="server" />
```

Would be

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelItem" Text="<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>" runat="server" />
```

Or

If you have to use Value of check box, then access value not Text

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelItem" value="<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>" runat="server" />

int departmentId = int.Parse(chkSelItem.Attributes["value"].ToString());
```

Comment: its working Adil, but I need to hide the `Text` value, wait am working on that as per SimplyVaibh's solution, I'll let u know once its done

Comment: You are welcome you can get value by chkSelItem .Attributes["value"].ToString();

Comment: Update my answer, this can get the value of checkbox.

Comment: thanks Adil, for ur kind response, am in great confusion to which answer I've to mark as accepted

Answer (score 1):

**In Aspx page:**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelItem" Text="<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>" runat="server" />
```

In code-behind add a check to ensure the item is not null:

```
    CheckBox chkSelItem = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelItem");

    if (chkSelItem != null && chkSelItem.Checked && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(chkSelItem.Text))
    {

        int departmentId = int.Parse(chkSelItem.Text);                
    }
```